# Div Next To Circle

Tags: css

```
<article style="max-width:500px;" class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="month"><?php the_time(d) ?></div>
        <div class="year"><?php the_time('M Y');?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thot">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <?php the_excerpt('Read More'); ?>
        <hr />
    </div>
</article>


<style>
.circle {
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    color:black;
    line-height:35px;
}
.month{
    font-size:60px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.year{
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>
```

What is the best way to move the "thot" div next to the "circle" div?

("Cirle") [POST aka "thot div"]

Link http://ramovamusic.com/?page_id=165

Example: ramovamusic.com/example.jpg

Comment: you have to show all your css/html - probably a link would do best

Comment: i have added the link

Comment: like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/75tn8yps/2/

Comment: I said this in my answer but, I feel the problem is you have a max width on your article tag. You need to remove that or increase to fit everything. Then what I did was float the circle left and float the class thot right. Giving them both a width will also help. You will need to play around to get the exactly how you want them. I also noticed your using display table cell... why?

Comment: I will look at demo in a second. table-cell was used because it was the only way I found to center multiple lines of text in a circle (it was an example from here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your circle div and some right margin, and for the .date class, add:

```
.date {
transform: translateY(-50%);
width: 165px;
top: 50%;
position: relative;
}
```

for `.thot` class add:

```
.thot {
  float:left;
  width: 300px; /* or whatever width works for you */
}
```

and finally you need to clear floats:

```
.post:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: what do i add the data class too?

Comment: This just moved the title inside the circle. I want the layout as it is now, just to move all the data within the "thot" div to the right of the circle div

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. Pleas see updated example image in the main post

Answer (score 1):

So now that I understand your question. The problem is you have a set width on your article tag (500px) this needs to be increased so you can float your class circle and class thot. that way they will be next to each other.

Here is a working demo as to what I am talking about  [New Demo Working](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/75tn8yps/5/)

Notice I removed the width on the article, added float right and width to class thot and float left on the circle. And now they are on the same line. You need to fiddle with it a bit to align it to your linking.

html:

```
<article style="" class="post" id="post-171">
<div class="circle">
    <div class="month">20</div>
    <div class="year">Mar 2015</div>
</div>
<div class="thot">
    <h4><a href="http://ramovamusic.com/?p=171" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to test 2">test 2</a></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tellus urna, mollis in nibh nec, fermentum rhoncus lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus ante arcu, laoreet ut efficitur vel, ornare sed risus. Cras eget interdum erat, finibus facilisis justo. Nam lorem mi, laoreet at dui non, rutrum semper felis. <a class="read-more" href="http://ramovamusic.com/?p=171">Read More</a></p>
    <hr />
</div>
</article>
```

css:

```
.circle {
   height: 165px;
   width: 165px;
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
   color: #000;
    line-height: 35px;
    float:left;
}
.thot{
   float:right;
   width:60%;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry the title was misleading. It should be the div next to the circle. But Either way this does not work, because my cirlce contains mutliple lines of text not just one.

Comment: Where the circle supposed to be on your site. Beside the title or the text?

Comment: Both. The Title and the Text are both in the "thot" div this should be floated next to the circle.

(circle)[Entire Post With Title]

Comment: I have added a picture example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, better to apply the circle in a span to keep all the text together! Otherwise it can end up getting tricky like you saw!

https://jsfiddle.net/75tn8yps/3/

```
div{
    float:left;
}
span.circle{
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 95px;
    text-align:center;
}
p{
   text-align:center;
   margin-top:40px;
}
```

Comment: This does not allow for multiple lines of text

Comment: It's going to be pretty tricky to match a mass of text, let a lone in a circle. You may need a rethink...

Answer (score 0):

[Demo In Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vdq93jt/)

I did change few things in the CSS File

```
.circle {
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    color:black;

    position:absolute;
}
.month{
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    line-height:90px;  
}
.year{
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;
    line-height:60px;  
}
.thot{
    border:1px solid black;    
    float:right;
    width: calc(100% - 180px);
    height:200px;
    position:relative;

}
```

The new CSS. Check The fiddle.

Comment: This almost works, but if there are multiple posts, all the circles go to the top left corner of the first post.